# Mathematica inconsistent output for integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Plot[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

The graph is easily seen to be symmetric about $\pi$.

But

```
Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, 0, Pi}]
```

gives the correct answer of `2.0944` but

```
Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, Pi, 2*Pi}]
```

outputs `-8.37758`

It turns out that

```
Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

does work giving double the previous answer: `4.18879`

Why??? This is driving me insane.

Comment: I'm not sure why it gives bad result, but it is generally considered a bad idea to use inexact numbers with symbolic computation. Use `1/4`, not `0.25`.

Comment: @Szabolcs That fixes it... thank you. Very strange!

Comment: Be aware that your integrand changes sign in the integration range. With Mathematica v11 the two   integrals  evaluate to  2.0944 which seems to be true `Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, 0, Pi}] == 
 Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, Pi, 2 *Pi}] (* True*)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at your integral, you find the following:

```
expr = Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 1/4), x];
Plot[expr, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The value at `Pi` is `Indeterminate` and with this knowledge, it is clear that you need to look at the limit from the right side to calculate your integral correctly:

```
(expr /. x -> 2 Pi) - Limit[expr, x -> Pi, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
(* (2 π)/3 *)
```

What Mathematica does instead is that it uses the limit from the wrong side when you use 0.25 instead of exact values

```
(expr /. x -> 2 Pi) - Limit[expr, x -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow"]
N[%]
(* -((8 π)/3) *)
(* -8.37758 *)
```

That being said, you have to be careful and it is one of those cases where you cannot assume that using Mathematica is an excuse to not think about your problem.

Comment: Oh boy. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @bwv869 Btw, my last paragraph should by no means sound accusing. It is serious advice that you look into simple examples like this carefully because they are small enough to see the whole picture. Once you face a difficult problem, you need many of such training sessions to know how to tackle them. For instance, now you should know, why this gives such a vastly different result `Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, Pi - .001, 2 Pi}]`

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the results of the question:

Looking at the integrand

```
Plot[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 1/4), {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},GridLines -> {{-2 Pi, -Pi, Pi, 2 Pi}, None}]
```

[image]

I see this function. The "areas" in the ranges [0,Pi] and [Pi,2 Pi] are equal!

Mathematica v11.0.1 confirms

```
Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, 0, Pi}] ==Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, Pi, 2 *Pi}]
(* True *)
```

and evaluates both integrals

```
Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, 0, Pi}](*2.0944*)
Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, Pi, 2 *Pi}](*2.0944*)
```

The sum of both gives

```
Integrate[Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 0.25), {x, 0, 2 *Pi}](*4.18879==2*2.0944*)
```

Comment: I can reproduce it in M11.2.  The second number in the version is just as relevant as the first.  There's as much difference between M11.0 and M11.1 as there was between M10.4 and M11.0.  It's best to state at least the first two part of the version every time.

Comment: Thanks. My version is 11.0.1. Perhaps I should wait with the update ;-)

Comment: halirutan showed that the problem is that with the inexact number the limit is taken from the wrong side. I think M11.1 introduced big changes (and many improvements) for limits.

Comment: Looking at the integrand the jump-effect is surprising for me. Checking numerically `Table[NIntegrate[
  Cos[x]/(1 - Cos[x] + 1/4), {x, 0, 
   Pi + \[CurlyEpsilon]}]  , {\[CurlyEpsilon], -.001, .001 , .001} ](*{2.09484, 2.0944, 2.09395}*)` seems to confirm my expectation.